# Category of sorting algorithm and complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, complexity

Just for fun, I wrote a sorting algorithm. I did not compare this with existing sorting algorithms.Can someone tell me what class of sorting algorithm this is and it's complexity? The algorithm primarily loops thru all elements finding the lowest in the array and removing them from the array from further processing. [taking duplicates into account]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] s = { 90,90, 71, 82, 93, 75, 81, 54, 36, 102, 99, 34, -56,-56, 103, 78,796,52,5,215 };
    Console.WriteLine($"Before sort: {string.Join(",", s)}");
    int[] sorted = new int[s.Length];
    int lowestNumber = 0;
    int[] removedOccurenceArray = s;
    bool isNonDuplicateMinFound = false; //checks if the same number has been processed before.            
    int occurenceCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) //First number in array check
        {
            sorted[i] = FindLowestNumber(s[i], s);
        }
        else
        {
            //remove the last foudn lowest number from array and also get the occurence count
            removedOccurenceArray = RemoveOccurenceFromArray(lowestNumber, removedOccurenceArray, out occurenceCount);
            if (occurenceCount > 1) //if more than 1 occurence found
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < occurenceCount - 1; j++) //-1 here as the lowest number was already added once in the previous iteration. J starts from 0 as i was already incremented and pointing to the next element in array
                {
                    sorted[i + j] = lowestNumber;
                }
                i = i + (occurenceCount-1); //occurenceCount-1 as the number was already inserted once before
            }
            occurenceCount = 0;
            int ctr = 0;
            while (!isNonDuplicateMinFound)
            {                        
                var l = FindLowestNumber(removedOccurenceArray[ctr], removedOccurenceArray);
                if (!sorted.Contains(l))
                {
                    sorted[i] = l;                                           
                    isNonDuplicateMinFound = true;
                }
                ctr++;
            }
            isNonDuplicateMinFound = false;
        }
        lowestNumber = sorted[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"After sort : {string.Join(",", sorted)}");
    Console.ReadLine();


}
/// <summary>
/// Takes a number and removes it from array giving out a new array and also outputing the number of occurences of that number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="numberToRemove"></param>
/// <param name="s"></param>
/// <param name="occurenceCount"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static int[] RemoveOccurenceFromArray(int numberToRemove, int[] s, out int occurenceCount)
{
    int[] tmpmoddedArray = new int[s.Length];
    int ctr = 0;
    int zeroCtr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != numberToRemove)
        {
            tmpmoddedArray[ctr] = s[i];
        }
        else
            zeroCtr++;

        ctr++;
    }
    //if we can do a dynamic re-size of the array, we can get rid of this second loop
    int[] moddedArray = new int[tmpmoddedArray.Length - zeroCtr];
    ctr = 0;
    int skipCtr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= tmpmoddedArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (tmpmoddedArray[i] != 0)
        {
            moddedArray[ctr] = tmpmoddedArray[ctr + skipCtr];
            ctr++;
        }
        else
            skipCtr++;


    }
    occurenceCount = zeroCtr;
    return moddedArray;
}      
private static int FindLowestNumber(int numberToCompare, int[] set)
{
    int lowestNumber = numberToCompare;            
    if (set.Length == 1)
        return set[0];// this is the last number, just  return it
    for (int i = 0; i <= set.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (set[i] == 0)
            continue;
        else if (set[i] <= lowestNumber)
            lowestNumber = set[i];                
    }
    return lowestNumber;
}
```

Comment: [Related Meta discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8373/9357)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requests an explanation of code (even if only the complexity), [which has been decided is off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6965/73844).

Comment: @EBrown This question does not ask about what the code does, it asks about if there is any common name for this sorting algorithm. The OP explains what the code does - *"The algorithm primarily loops thru all elements finding the lowest in the array and removing them from the array from further processing. [taking duplicates into account]"*

Comment: @SimonForsberg *"Can someone tell me what class of sorting algorithm this is and it's complexity?"* - that tells me that *not only* did the OP put minimal research effort into it, but they just expect someone to provide them with an explanation of the complexity. That's not what we're here for - we're here to make code better, not tell someone what the running-time complexity of their algorithm is.

Comment: @teeboy: Would you like to know if your code speed can be improved somehow? Why are you interested in knowing the complexity and the class of sorting algorithm it is? What do you want to do with the information then?

Comment: @SimonForsberg . Just want to find out if I created a new sorting algorithm design :) Just kidding. I recently became interested in algorithm design after doing a few online tests.Just wanted to find out how good/bad I can do..  that's all...

Comment: And when you want to find out how good/bad you can do, are you also interested in improving yourself and the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I am @simonforsberg

Comment: Then please state that in the question @teeboy.

Answer (score 1):

It is at O(n^3) as remove alone is O(n)

Consider this

```
int lowestNumber = numberToCompare;            
if (set.Length == 1)
    return set[0];// this is the last number, just  return it
for (int i = 0; i <= set.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (set[i] == 0)
        continue;
    else if (set[i] <= lowestNumber)
        lowestNumber = set[i];                
}
return lowestNumber;
```

`if (set.Length == 1)` serves no purpose.  The loop would just run once.

Why are you ignoring `if (set[i] == 0)`

Why are you not tracking duplicate positions of minimum in that loop?  It would be almost free.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (i == 0) //First number in array check
    {
        sorted[i] = FindLowestNumber(s[i], s);
    }
```

to

```
sorted[0] = FindLowestNumber(s[0], s);
for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
{
```

If `lowestNumber` is increasing then why does it need to be removed from the array?

I doubt I could write a less efficient sort if I tried.

If you are going to do O(n^2) at least do it in one pass each

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Sorted(int[] set)
{
    int count;
    int maxMin = int.MinValue;
    while ( (maxMin = Min(set, maxMin, out count)) != int.MaxValue )
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            yield return maxMin;
    };
}
public static int Min(int[] set, int maxMin, out int count)
{
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    count = 1;
    foreach (int i in set)
    {
        if (i == min)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if(i > maxMin && i < min)
        {
            min = i;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Lowest number has to be removed so that it does not get counted again . Consider this array: {12,15,10,9,18,14}. You start with 12 compare it with all numbers. Got 9 in first pass. I strip 9 out from the 2nd pass as it's already accounted for. you go to 15 and compare it with all numbers. You get 10. You remove 10 from next pass. Next, you pick 10. But, 10 is already processed, so move to next one. You pick 9. 9 is also already processed. move to next one. Pick 18. out of 18 and 14, you get 14 as lowest and the last number is 18. That is the algorithm.

Comment: Not if you are smart enough to only consider numbers > 9.

Comment: Your algorithm is very good. my intention is not to use any of the built in .net libraries and just use arrays. I accept that my algorithm needs improvement